# I have no idea why I get an error when putting the foreing keys in MariaDB

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, mariadb

I have no idea why I get an error when putting the foreing keys in MariaDB

I drop the full database if it exists

```
drop database if exists proveedoresCarrito;
create database proveedoresCarrito;
use proveedoresCarrito;
```

And now I'm going to create the tables

```
CREATE TABLE INVENTARIO (
NUMPIEZA CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
NUMBIN SMALLINT NOT NULL,
CANTDISPONIBLE SMALLINT,
FECHARECUENTO DATE,
PERIODORECUEN SMALLINT,
CANTAJUSTE SMALLINT,
CARTREORD SMALLINT,
PUNTOREORD SMALLINT);


CREATE TABLE LINPED (
NUMPEDIDO SMALLINT NOT NULL,
NUMLINEA SMALLINT NOT NULL,
NUMPIEZA CHAR(16),
PRECIOCOMPRA INTEGER,
CANTPEDIDA SMALLINT,
FECHARECEP DATE,
CANTRECIBIDA SMALLINT);


CREATE TABLE PEDIDO (
NUMPEDIDO SMALLINT NOT NULL,
NUMVEND SMALLINT,
FECHA DATE);


CREATE TABLE PIEZA (
NUMPIEZA CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
NOMPIEZA CHAR(30),
PRECIOVENT INTEGER);


CREATE TABLE PRECIOSUM (
NUMPIEZA CHAR(16) NOT NULL,
NUMVEND SMALLINT NOT NULL,
PRECIOUNIT INTEGER,
DIASSUM SMALLINT,
DESCUENTO SMALLINT);


CREATE TABLE VENDEDOR (
NUMVEND SMALLINT NOT NULL,
NOMVEND CHAR(30),
NOMBRECOMER CHAR(30),
TELEFONO CHAR(15),
CALLE CHAR(30),
CIUDAD CHAR(20),
PROVINCIA CHAR(20),
COD_POSTAL CHAR(5));

create table usuarios(
nombre SMALLINT NOT NULL,
pass CHAR(15)
);
```

I Set up the primary keys

```
ALTER TABLE INVENTARIO ADD CONSTRAINT CP_INVENTARIO PRIMARY KEY (NUMBIN);
ALTER TABLE LINPED ADD CONSTRAINT CP_LINPED PRIMARY KEY (NUMPEDIDO, NUMLINEA);
ALTER TABLE PEDIDO ADD CONSTRAINT CP_PEDIDO PRIMARY KEY (NUMPEDIDO);
ALTER TABLE PIEZA ADD CONSTRAINT CP_PIEZA PRIMARY KEY (NUMPIEZA);
ALTER TABLE PRECIOSUM ADD CONSTRAINT CP_PRECIOSUM PRIMARY KEY (NUMPIEZA, NUMVEND);
ALTER TABLE VENDEDOR ADD CONSTRAINT CP_VENDEDOR PRIMARY KEY (NUMVEND);
```

AND FINALLY i set up the foreign keys

```
ALTER TABLE INVENTARIO ADD CONSTRAINT CP_INVENTARIO PRIMARY KEY (NUMBIN);
ALTER TABLE LINPED ADD CONSTRAINT CP_LINPED PRIMARY KEY (NUMPEDIDO, NUMLINEA);
ALTER TABLE PEDIDO ADD CONSTRAINT CP_PEDIDO PRIMARY KEY (NUMPEDIDO);
ALTER TABLE PIEZA ADD CONSTRAINT CP_PIEZA PRIMARY KEY (NUMPIEZA);
ALTER TABLE PRECIOSUM ADD CONSTRAINT CP_PRECIOSUM PRIMARY KEY (NUMPIEZA, NUMVEND);
ALTER TABLE VENDEDOR ADD CONSTRAINT CP_VENDEDOR PRIMARY KEY (NUMVEND);
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT CA_VENDEDOR_USUARIOS_NOMBRE FOREIGN KEY (nombre) REFERENCES VENDEDOR(NUMVEND);
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT CA_VENDEDOR_USUARIOS_PASS FOREIGN KEY (pass) REFERENCES VENDEDOR(TELEFONO);
```

However, all the foreign keys work correctly except for the last two
when i run the sql script i get this error:

Error de SQL (1822): Failed to add the foreign key constaint. Missing index for constraint 'CA_VENDEDOR_USUARIOS_PASS' in the referenced table 'vendedor'

if I drop the last two foreign keys the error disappears

Anyone can give me a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look closely at your "set up the foreign keys" code. It creates primary keys again (except the two last lines).

Table `usuarios` seems to have no primary key.

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT CP_usuarios PRIMARY KEY (nombre);
```

Delete the first 6 lines and keep only these

```
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT CA_VENDEDOR_USUARIOS_NOMBRE
    FOREIGN KEY (nombre)
    REFERENCES VENDEDOR(NUMVEND);
ALTER TABLE usuarios ADD CONSTRAINT CA_VENDEDOR_USUARIOS_PASS
    FOREIGN KEY (pass)
    REFERENCES VENDEDOR(TELEFONO);
```

Also (and this is what generates your error), you are trying to add a foreign key to a column `VENDEDOR(TELEFONO)` which is not a primary key nor has a  UNIQUE constraint.

According to Microsoft:

> A foreign key constraint does not have to be linked only to a primary key constraint in another table; it can also be defined to reference the columns of a UNIQUE constraint in another table.

See: [Create Foreign Key Relationships](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/create-foreign-key-relationships)

Add this before creating the foreign keys:

```
ALTER TABLE VENDEDOR ADD CONSTRAINT UX_telefono UNIQUE (TELEFONO);
```

Comment: Thanks you! its impossible to put a foreign key that does not reference to a primary key, however i dont want to put ALTER TABLE VENDEDOR ADD CONSTRAINT UX_telefono UNIQUE (TELEFONO); because this field have to be able to repeat, ¿its there any alternative to Foreign Key?

Comment: Add a foreign key to the primary key of the vendor whose phone number is referenced. I.e., replace the `pass` column by a `pass_vendor_id` column. Then look up the phone number in the vendor, when you need it. This way it is more normalized as you don't repeat the phone number.

Comment: But, how i can look up and use the phone number like a password without a foreign key?

Comment: I only know how to obtain a value from another table using a foreign key

Comment: The foreign key is only there to enforce referential integrity, not to allow lookups. To speed up lookups, all you need is an index (unique or not), but lookups work without referential integrity or indexes as well. A phone number as password wouldn’t be a safe password, would it?

Comment: You obtain a value from another table by using a query, not by using a foreign key.
  `SELECT v.NOMVEND, v.TELEFONO FROM VENDEDOR WHERE v.NUMVEND = xy`

Comment: Thank you very much, I am really grateful for your help

Answer (score 0):

A foreign key has to reference always a primary key.

For you to reference the table VENDEDOR you should use the columns that compose its PK. In this example, NUMVEND.

If you need any suggestions on what to do, i'd have to know what are your intentions on this DB structure.